# how to set ID to dynamically created text box in JavaScript

Tags: c#, php, javascript, asp.net

''m trying to set the `ID` for dynamically created text box using JavaScript and code like fallows...

here QTY is Dropdown list

like..
**HTML Code**

```
 <select id="Qty" name="childQty" onChange="changeIt()">
        <option value="0">ZERO</option>
        <option value="1">ONE</option>
        <option value="2">TWO</option>
        <option value="3">THREE</option>
        <option value="4">FOUR</option>
        <option value="5">FIVE</option>
    </select>

<div id="my_div"><input type="hidden" /></div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
function changeIt()
        {
        var sel = document.getElementById('Qty');
        var i = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

        my_div.innerHTML ="";
        var txtid="";
        for(var j=0;j<i;j++){
        txtid='mytext'+j;
        //alert(txtid);
                my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name=txtid id='txtid'>"

            }

        }
```

Here am trying to set `txtid` to the `id` of that text boxes which are going to create inside `my_div.innerHTML` but this is not working `txtid='mytext'+j;` and then i want to concat those all text which user will enter in the dynamically created text boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this Line:

```
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name=txtid id='txtid'>"
```

should be

```
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name=txtid id='+txtid+'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name=txtid id='"+ txtid +"'>"
```